# Dominant colors with Image package in python

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have a transparent image and I am trying to extract major colors out of it using `Image` module's `getcolor()` method

```
y = Image.open('img.png')
y.getcolors()
[Out]: [(21841, 0),
(13328, 1),
 (8171, 2),
 (2673, 3),
 (1337, 4),
 (1010, 5),
 (892, 6),
 (519, 7),
 (379, 8),
 (234, 9)]
```

How do I get actual color values (or names) corresponding to these indexes?

[image]

Comment: So, essentially I search through the whole image to get which (x,y) pixels have id of 0 or 1, and then convert the image to RGB, and then get the RGB values at those (x,y). There is got to be a better way!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether the following code snippet is what you are finding. Convert the `Image` object to RGBA object and use `getcolors()` as follows.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('img.png')
rgba_im = im.convert('RGBA')
print ( rgba_im.getcolors() )

"""
<Output>
[(2673, (218, 215, 209, 255)), (379, (195, 29, 54, 255)), (21841, (208, 208, 209, 0)), (234, (206, 198, 185, 255)), (519, (201, 178, 176, 255)), (1337, (193, 188, 186, 0)), (8171, (182, 176, 174, 0)), (892, (178, 170, 165, 255)), (13328, (168, 26, 41, 255)), (1010, (107, 18, 19, 255))]
"""
```